# Codeigniter routing best practices

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a CMS-like website for myself and one component will be a blog. Ideally, I'd like the routes to be /blog-category/blog-slug

I'm wondering what the best way to achieve this would be?

I'll have a table for categories and a table for the individual posts.

A possible solution would be to use:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'blogController/getBlogPost'
```

However, I suspect this would have an effect on performance, I'd rather not send all requests to the posts controller, I'd rather just send them to the correct controller from the routes files.

Is there another way to loop through the categories and make a dynamic route?

Tom

Comment: The uri routing user guide here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use correct route as:

```
$route['blog-category/(:any)'] = 'blogController/blogFunction/$1';
```

For this URL:

```
/blog-category/blog-slug
```

In route `$1` is using for your `slug`.

Comment: But then I would have to make a new route for every category.

Comment: @tom if blog-category dynamic than: $route['category/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'blogController/blogFunction/$1/$2';

Comment: $1 for category $2 for slug @tom